# Mysql datetime count the hours worked between a specific time

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to count the hours worked between a given time range.

For example to count from the MySQL data below the hours worked between 22:00 and 06:00.

Using date_start `2022-04-01 21:00:00` and date_end `2022-04-02 08:00:00` the user worked `11 hours total` and `8 night hours`.

Of course the data could also be something like `2022-04-01 05:00:00` and `2022-04-01 16:00:00` which will then need to output `2 night hours` or `2022-04-01 18:00:00`and `2022-04-02 03:00:00` which outputs `5 night hours`.

MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`date_start`,`date_end`) VALUES 
('2022-04-01 04:00:00', '2022-04-01 16:00:00'), # 2:00 nighthours
('2022-04-02 05:00:00', '2022-04-02 23:30:00'), # 2:30 nighthours
('2022-04-03 06:00:00', '2022-04-03 18:00:00'), # 0:00 nighthours
('2022-04-04 12:00:00', '2022-04-05 00:00:00'), # 2:00 nighthours
('2022-04-05 19:00:00', '2022-04-06 07:00:00'); # 8:00 nighthours
```

Current MySQL:

```
# 21600 = 06:00 hours
# 79200 = 22:00 hours

SELECT t.date_start, t.date_end, DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(
(CASE WHEN DATE(t.date_start) != DATE(t.date_end) AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_end) > 21600 THEN DATE_FORMAT(t.date_end, '%Y-%m-%d 06:%i:%s')
WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_start) < 21600 THEN DATE_FORMAT(t.date_start, '%Y-%m-%d 06:%i:%s')
ELSE t.date_end END), 
(CASE WHEN DATE(t.date_start) != DATE(t.date_end) AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_start) < 79200 THEN DATE_FORMAT(t.date_start, '%Y-%m-%d 22:%i:%s')
WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_end) > 79200 THEN DATE_FORMAT(t.date_start, '%Y-%m-%d 22:%i:%s')
WHEN DATE(t.date_start) = DATE(t.date_end) AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_end) <= 79200 AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.date_start) >= 21600 THEN t.date_end
ELSE t.date_start END)
), '%H:%i') AS night_time FROM tasks t;
```

Currently I still have a problem in my current MySQL when the `start_date` and `end_date` both start on the same day and both have night hours. for example `2022-04-02 05:00:00` and `2022-04-02 23:30:00` which has 01:00 night hour in `start_date` and 1:30 hour in `end_date` (total night: 02:30 hours)

I am not sure if my current MySQL is the best/fastest way to achieve my goal.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Please state clearly when night hours start and stop.

Comment: (Edit) Can the date range ever span _more_ than 24 hours? Also, why would you expect 2 hours for '2022-04-01 05:00:00' to '2022-04-02 16:00:00', since they're more than 35 hours apart - is that a typo?

Comment: @SOS It was a typo thanks to point out. A date range cannot reach more than 24 hours.

Comment: @SOS i updated my code with my current progress and also added example data.

Comment: Try this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43ef646f4f03ab9677b85a3078ac8b86

Comment: @SOS Thank you for your input, it works correctly. ill try now to also add late time (19:00 - 22:00) to your code.

Comment: It works for my sample data so you can post your result as an answer.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculating Time Overlaps

You can calculate the amount of time two date ranges overlap using:

- `MIN( EndDate1, EndDate2 ) - MAX( StartDate1, StartDate2 )`

For example if the date ranges are:

| Date_Start | Date_End | Night_Shift_Start | Night_Shift_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 21:00:00 | 2022-04-02 08:00:00 | 2022-04-01 22:00:00 ** | 2022-04-02 06:00:00 ** |

The result would be 8 hours:

| Min( EndDate ) - Max( StartDate ) | .... As Unix Timestamps | Time Overlap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-02 06:00:00 *(minus)* 2022-04-01 22:00:00 | 1648875600 - 1648846800 = 28800 seconds | 08:00:00 hours |

### Checking for Multiple Overlaps

Since technically a single shift could have both started *and* ended during "night hours" (22:00 to 06:00) you need check for overlaps on both sides.

| Date_Start | Date_End | Night Hours | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-05 05:00:00 | 2022-04-05 23:30:00 | 2.5 hours | *(1 hour)* : 2022-04-05 **05:00** to 2022-04-05 **06:00** *(1.5 hours)* : 2022-04-05 **22:00** to 2022-04-05 **23:30** |

One approach is using the base start/end times to calculate the previous and upcoming "night hour" periods:

```
SELECT  *
        , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '22:00:00') AS current_start
        , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start), '06:00:00') AS current_end
        , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start), '22:00:00') AS next_start
        , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '06:00:00') AS next_end
FROM   tasks
```

**Results:**

| id | date_start | date_end | current_start | current_end | next_start | next_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 04:00:00 | 2022-04-01 16:00:00 | 2022-03-31 22:00:00 | 2022-04-01 06:00:00 | 2022-04-01 22:00:00 | 2022-04-02 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-04-02 05:00:00 | 2022-04-02 23:30:00 | 2022-04-01 22:00:00 | 2022-04-02 06:00:00 | 2022-04-02 22:00:00 | 2022-04-03 06:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-04-03 06:00:00 | 2022-04-03 18:00:00 | 2022-04-02 22:00:00 | 2022-04-03 06:00:00 | 2022-04-03 22:00:00 | 2022-04-04 06:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-04-04 12:00:00 | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | 2022-04-03 22:00:00 | 2022-04-04 06:00:00 | 2022-04-04 22:00:00 | 2022-04-05 06:00:00 |
| 5 | 2022-04-05 19:00:00 | 2022-04-06 07:00:00 | 2022-04-04 22:00:00 | 2022-04-05 06:00:00 | 2022-04-05 22:00:00 | 2022-04-06 06:00:00 |
| 6 | 2022-04-01 04:00:00 | 2022-04-01 16:00:00 | 2022-03-31 22:00:00 | 2022-04-01 06:00:00 | 2022-04-01 22:00:00 | 2022-04-02 06:00:00 |
| 7 | 2022-04-05 19:00:00 | 2022-04-06 07:00:00 | 2022-04-04 22:00:00 | 2022-04-05 06:00:00 | 2022-04-05 22:00:00 | 2022-04-06 06:00:00 |
| 8 | 2022-04-05 05:00:00 | 2022-04-05 23:30:00 | 2022-04-04 22:00:00 | 2022-04-05 06:00:00 | 2022-04-05 22:00:00 | 2022-04-06 06:00:00 |

### Total Overlap Time

Once you have the "night hour" ranges, calculate the overlapping time on both sides and add them together to get the total time worked during "night hours"

```
SELECT id
       , date_start
       , date_end
       , SEC_TO_TIME( 
            GREATEST(0, start_overlap__in_seconds)  -- ignore negative time, which means no overlap
            + GREATEST(0, end_overlap_in_seconds)
       ) AS time_overall
FROM  ( 
          SELECT * 
                 , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAST(date_end, current_end))
                   - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GREATEST(date_start, current_start))
                 AS start_overlap__in_seconds                   
                 , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LEAST(date_end,next_end))
                   - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GREATEST(date_start,next_start))
                 AS end_overlap_in_seconds                   
          FROM  (
                  SELECT  *
                          , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '22:00:00') AS current_start
                          , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start), '06:00:00') AS current_end
                          , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start), '22:00:00') AS next_start
                          , TIMESTAMP(DATE(date_start) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '06:00:00') AS next_end
                  FROM   tasks
                ) tmp 
     ) t
```

**Final Results:**

| id | date_start | date_end | time_overall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 04:00:00 | 2022-04-01 16:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-04-02 05:00:00 | 2022-04-02 23:30:00 | 02:30:00 |
| 3 | 2022-04-03 06:00:00 | 2022-04-03 18:00:00 | 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-04-04 12:00:00 | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
| 5 | 2022-04-05 19:00:00 | 2022-04-06 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 |
| 6 | 2022-04-01 04:00:00 | 2022-04-01 16:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
| 7 | 2022-04-05 19:00:00 | 2022-04-06 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 |
| 8 | 2022-04-05 05:00:00 | 2022-04-05 23:30:00 | 02:30:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3897f41fb364d7ea08bad24506f8665d)*